# Jquery File download ($.fileDownload)

Tags: jquery, download

I am using jquery file download ..

the code is as follows :

```
 function downloadFile(){
var downloadOptions = {
preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
failMessageHtml: "No reports generated. No Survey data is available."
                  };

     $.fileDownload("displaySurveyReport.action",downloadOptions);
return false; 
}
```

This is what i am doing at button click

When i click on the button , the preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...", is shown in a dialog box ...
The problem is that this dialog box does not go off after the fle completes its preparing and i have to close it manually ... 
How can i make it go off when the file completes its preparation and is ready to download..

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to make JQuery knows the file download just ocurred, your response header must contains `Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/`.

In Java:

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
```

Comment: Thanx we have to set the cookies and tell the browser when the file download is going to start

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158481/execution-order-of-http-response-headers

Comment: In asp.net mvc C# I used : 
Response.AppendHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");

Answer (score 3):

Here is source code of jquery file download ..

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadCustomRichExperience", function () {

        var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");

        $preparingFileModal.dialog({ modal: true });

        $.fileDownload($(this).attr('href'), {
            successCallback: function (url) {

                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
            },
            failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
                $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true });
            }
        });
        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
    });
});

<div id="preparing-file-modal" title="Preparing report..." style="display: none;">
    We are preparing your report, please wait...

    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="width: 100%; height:22px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
</div>

<div id="error-modal" title="Error" style="display: none;">
    There was a problem generating your report, please try again.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On sucess;

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

On error

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=false; path=/");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

Use "Cache-Control" only if will exists anothers requests.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers also need you to reset response or your download will not work!

```
response.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

please try like this

```
function exportToExcelTest() {
        var region = $('#ddlRegion').val();
        var hrinfo = $('#hrinfodropdown').val();
        if (region != null) {
            $('#ExportOptions').modal('hide');
            $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Please wait generating excel data...</h1>' });
            //$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="../Images/ajax_loader_blue_350.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
            $.blockUI({ css: { backgroundColor: '#f00', color: '#fff'} });
            var myData = region + ':' + hrinfo;

            $.fileDownload('Excel.ashx', {
                httpMethod: "POST",
                data: { data: myData },
                successCallback: function (url) {
                    //$("div#loading").hide();
                    //alert('ok');
                    //response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=false; path=/");
                    $.unblockUI();
                },
                prepareCallback: function (url) {
                    //alert('ok');
                    //response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
                    $.unblockUI();
                },
                failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
                    //alert('ok');
                    // $("div#loading").hide();
                    // alert('Error while generating excel file');
                    //response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=false; path=/");
                    $.unblockUI();
                }
            });          
        }
        else {
            alert('Please select a region....');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Referance from : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28713105/Jquery-fileDownload-successcallback-not-working.html

I hope it's Work for you..