# Execution order of Http Response headers?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, http-headers, fiddler

I saw *[this plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)*  which download files using Ajax *and* some other fallback techniques.

But since ajax download file feature is not supported in all browsers , he used a trick with Iframe. ( which is pretty easy to implement)

But one thing caught my eye :

> He also added an option which tells you when the file  has finished 
>   download.

He  did it via `cookie`.  He polls to see if the `cookie` via `setInterval`. as long as the `cookie` does not exist - the file wasn't finish download.( and when the `cookie` is present - the file has downloaded)

So the header for downloading a file is:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report0.pdf`

And he added :

`Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/`

But then I thought - who said that  `set-cookie` is called **after** the file has finish downloaded ?

**Questions:**

Looking at the actual headers :

[image]

**1 -** Does the browser *digest* each  header according to the actual order of appearance ?

**2 -** Are there any headers which must appear **prior** to other headers ?

**3 -** Does the  digest of each header - blocks the digest until current hedare digest is completed ? I mean : does the line `content-disposition:attachment;filename=1.jpg` prevents the browser from  digesting the next header - until the `filename=1.jpg` is finished loading ?

nb

*I've also tried investigate it via fiddler but I didn't get any conclusion.( I mean how can I test it in fiddler ?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to be skeptical.

There's no requirement that a client wait until the response body is complete to evaluate the `Set-Cookie` header that preceded the body, and there's in fact good reason to believe that most browsers will set the cookie before the body is complete (since many web pages will look at `document.cookie` in JavaScript inside a HTML page).

In fact, I tested this (using a MeddlerScript you can see here: http://pastebin.com/SUwCFyxS) and found that IE, Chrome and Firefox all set the cookie before the download completes, and set the cookie even if the user hits "Cancel" on the download.

The HTTP specification includes the notion of a `Trailer` (which is a header that appears after the response body) but these are little used and not supported in many clients (e.g. WinINET/IE). If the client *did* support Trailers, the server could send the Set-Cookie header *after* the body which would mean that the client couldn't see it until the body finished downloading.

Comment: But Eric , Is it possible that those rules are not applied when the response is an attachment ?(`content-disposition:attachment`) ? I mean - how do you explain that the cookie is set _after_ the 100% download of the file ? (i did test it...)

Comment: As I said, there's no requirement that a client wait until the response body is complete to evaluate the `Set-Cookie` header. Can you provide a repro URL that suggests that browsers *are* waiting?

Comment: So ,  the plugin code which is based on a cookie to tell if the file was downloaded - has a basic flaw assumption. (I'm asking cuz I'm going to implement it in my web site).(thanks Eric)

Comment: Yes, the cookie is set when the download **starts**. I built a test to prove it and updated my answer. If you read the original article, that's exactly what they're trying to do-- detect the **start** of the download, not the end. Having said that, even detecting the start is a bit sketchy, since you never know whether the user clicked **Cancel** in the middle.

Comment: Couldn't ask for more , Eric. Thank you